# Using Set polyfill in webpack doesn't resolve errors

Tags: typescript, webpack, polyfills

I'm seeing some "Can't find variable: Set" errors in production on older browsers. I figure this is Typescript and Webpack being ambitious about their usage of es6 features, no big deal, I can polyfill that just like I've polyfilled `Object.assign` for React.

Now my Polyfill config for webpack looks like this:

```
// using include in the callback selection requires a polyfill for ie
require('string.prototype.includes');

// some older browsers don't support Set, which apparently something compiles to
require('es6-set');

// fetch() polyfill for making API calls.
require('whatwg-fetch');

// Object.assign() is commonly used with React.
// It will use the native implementation if it's present and isn't buggy.
Object.assign = require('object-assign');
```

But after releasing and verifying the release is out, I'm still seeing errors in older browsers relating to Set. I've looked through the docs for adding polyfills to webpack and I don't see if I'm missing a step or why this isn't working.

What am I doing wrong, or what else can I try?

Comment: I think using core-js is sort of the standard for polyfills, but it looks like you're using https://github.com/medikoo/es6-set . If you look at the README, it says        "If you want to make sure your environment implements Set, do: `require('es6-set/implement');`.If you'd like to use native version when it exists and fallback to polyfill if it doesn't, but without implementing Set on global scope, do: `var Set = require('es6-set');`".         So it sounds like you should be using `require('es6-set/implement');` if you just want to set it once globally and not manage each usage.

Comment: @matmo maybe that's specific to es6-set and not how this usually works? I tried shipping the Set from `core-js`, let's see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
// some older browsers don't support Set, which apparently something compiles to
require('es6-set');
```

Does not follow the readme of the project : https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-set

## Fix

From the readme :

```
require('es6-set/implement');
```